# DDD modeling with subtypes

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I recently started learning about DDD and I'm in the process of designing a solution for an Auction module the issue I'm facing is that the different types of auctions have different characteristics for example:
I have Auction for License plates and when creating the Auction you should provide the base letters like "AAA, BCA, ..." and the items of the auction is going to be "AAA001, AAA002 etc..."
but somehow I need to tell that this auction is for License plates in the db so I need somehow to connect between the Auction and the base characters of the plates like the Auction id x is for "xxx" plate base.
so the auction type in my case is licensePlate auction and the items are of the following format (base characters + generated numbers).
so as per my study of the ddd I came up with the following:

```
class Auction
{
  AuctionId: Int
  StartAt: datetime
  Duration: Int
  MinStartAmount: decimal
  MinOutbidAmount: decimal
  AuctionType: byte
  AuctionItems: List<AuctionItems>
}

<<Entity>>
class AuctionItem
{
  AuctionItemId: Int
  Value: string
  Description: string
  AuctionId: Int                   
}
```

now in case we have in the future something like Cars auction for all cars engine size xxx
then the items I assume should be all cars of all models with engine size xxx.
and the auction is going to be Car Auction and of course I need to add the same above relationship between the auctionId and the engineSize in new table that define the CarAuction type.
keep in mind in the database we will have Auction table to store common details and many tables for information related to the type of the auction like LicensePlateAuction, CarAuction ...

so the question is should I have aggregates as many auction types as I get? or one aggregate (AuctionAggregate) is enough?

if multiple aggregates is the valid approach then where should the crud operations of the Auction table should sit?in which repo?

if one Aggregate is the valid approach then where should auction type's characteristics (LicensePlate base characters/EngineSize) should go?

Comment: DDD has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with solution design, and indeed the term 'entity' in DDD means something completely different to the term 'entity' in the context of relational databases.   The focus of DDD is about requirements analysis and building a conceptual domain model from those requirements, not an implementation model. You may sometimes find that your Domain entities just coincidentally happen to correlate to database tables, but this should not be a consequence of DDD, more a consequence of ordinary relational database design, putting the DB into 3rd normal form.

Comment: @BenCottrell I see.  do you have any suggestions in how to model such a requirement in ddd?

Comment: I don't see how the specific values of the plates that fall under a single auction impacts the design here. That seems more a matter of choosing which data to create, not how to model it.

Comment: If you talk to an auctioneer, how would they describe the set of license plates being auctioned? Would they describe it as "plates with base letters ABC and 2 digit sequence numbers", or would they describe it as "the set of plates provided to us by the DMV"? In the latter case, the generation of license plates would be completely separate from the auctioning of them and the auction part doesn't have to know how the plates are generated.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau they will describe it as an auction on the series ABC or ABD etc.
And you're right, the generation of license plates is completely separate, but as an auction domain shouldn't he need to define this series somewhere?

Comment: The auction domain does not necessarily need to know the series. It depend on how this is dealt with or discussed by the domain experts, but it is also possible that the auction domain just gets a set of auction items to sell and that only the domain providing those items knows that they come from the series ABC or ABD. The auction domain just has to know how the selling of those items works.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau it sounds very logical.
just for me to understand, if auctioning the license plate is different from auctioning any another item, I mean it has it's own business rules and invariants, could we consider License plate auction as our problem space therefore to have LicenseAuctionAggregate and the Auction as an entity model?

Comment: I would suggest, much like @BenCottrell already mentioned, that you stop considering the structure of your persistence model. Focus on the core domain logic, without thinking of repositories and table structure. Instead, think of behaviour. You could define an `Auction` interface, with all the methods it should support, for example `addItemToAuction(AuctionItem)`. Now, if different types of auctions have different rules about what to add, how many items can be added, etc, you would have a specific implementation of this interface, `LicencePlateAuction implements Auction`

Comment: You could then model your UI/App/Infrastructure layer to expose your domain layer in whatever way is most suitable. Whether you decide on tables, single/class table inheritance, document/event store, you would evaluate based on what your specific use cases are. You would have to implement a mapping between your domain layer and persistence layer, though, and that's where this logic would belong.